# ERROR in WorkforceDetailsComponent is not an NgModule

Tags: angular

how to resolve the error

> ERROR in WorkforceDetailsComponent is not an NgModule

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  templateUrl: 'workforcedetails.component.html'
})

export class WorkforceDetailsComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: what error you are getting and where do you get?

Comment: @Aravind the title.. add the app.module.ts

Comment: which title? @suraj

Comment: "ERROR in WorkforceDetailsComponent is not an NgModule" the question title

Comment: Could you please provide the code from your NgModule? Or do you don't use it at all? A plunker would also help to provide a solution.

Comment: You are probably importing `WorkforceDetailsComponent` somewhere in your code as an `@NgModule` no?